# Odoo. Add user group after its creation

Tags: python, odoo

I have group:

```
<record id="group_profile" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Blog Content Editor</field>           
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>       
</record>
```

I need all new users to make automatic in this group.
I tried this:

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
        values = super(res_users, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context)
        group_id = self.pool.get('res.groups').search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', 'Blog Content Editor')], context=context)
        groups_ids = values['groups_id']
        groups_ids[0][-1].append(group_id[0])
        values['groups_id'] = groups_ids
        return values
```

But nothing works.

upd:

```
<record id="group_blog_content" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Blog Content Editor</field>
    <field name="comment">The Users from this group will have the access to modify blog content. </field>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>

<record id="base.group_user" model="res.groups">
     <field name="name">Employee</field>
     <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
     <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_blog_content'))]"/>
</record>
```

Not work (

Answer (score 0):

You want to add your new group to the `inherited_ids` of `base.group_user`.

```
<record id="base.group_user" model="res.groups">
   <field name="name">Employee</field>
   <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
   <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_profile'))]"></field>
</record>
```

this will works for **all** users not just new ones.

If you just want it for new users, please follow https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/how-to-enable-a-security-group-for-all-users-60530